# How to check user who opened the record in salesforce is the owner of the record?

Tags: salesforce

I am new to sales force. I'd be glad if you could clarify my question. question may be silly, but I am in learning phase, so please bear with me :)

1) User is  login into a sales force organization.
2) he is  opening a record, so we have to find out that is the user who opened the record is the record owner or not?

What I found is we have to write if-else block

If($userinfo.getUserId == recordId.Ownerid){

}else{}

other solutions would be helpful for me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to achieve. 
You can configure [sharing](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) of an object to be accessible only for owner. More info on sharing and record ownership [in this great post](http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2013/10/behind-the-scenes-of-record-ownership-in-salesforce.html)